# Looking for C# audio analysis libraries

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing

Im working on a Software Project where our team needs to record a train horn sound.  We have purchased the recorder; its saved as a .wav file.  We now need to extract data from the file like frequency and amplitude to create spectrum analysis and decibel level graphs. Any C# libraries out there for this type of thing?

Comment: Ach, I've just discovered the joy of tag-editting collisions.  :::Fixes:::

Answer (score 1):

We're using the Intel Performance Primitives library for this stuff (like FFT). It has a useable C# wrapper, or you can call it with P/Invoke

Answer (score 0):

This [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundViewer.aspx?fid=448560&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2202971) article has code that can grab amplitude and frequency. Not sure if that covers everything you need.