# C# Audio File Analysis API/Library?

Tags: c#, api, audio, waveform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for C# audio analysis libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947362/looking-for-c-sharp-audio-analysis-libraries)

Is there a library or api that allows for analysis of audio (possibly in real time)?

I ask with the eventual goal of creating a visualizer, so I want to see the volume, waveform and frequencies of an audio file.

Thanks.

Comment: The correct word is "analysis".  This may help you search more effectively for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Try the Mitov library - I cant get it to work with VS2010 but it works fine with VS2008 Express.  It has Sound, Audio, Plot and various video and instrumentation libraries.  You can select components such as audio in, spectrum analysis, waterfall displays (sonagrams), waveform displays, filters etc. etc. etc.  Very easy to use - just drag the components from the toolbox and select connections between them.  The Audio toolbox works with mono or stereo audio streams and the signal toolbox works with single streams of reals, with converters each way.  Should do everything you need.  Free for personal use.
http://mitov.com

Justin

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out http://naudio.codeplex.com/?